# How to set a background image in BrightScript for a particular screen?

Tags: roku, brightscript

How to set a background image in brightscript for a particular screen?

Is dfNewBitmapSet() the method used to set the background?!

kindly share your answers

Comment: You should be more specific what you are doing. Are you using `roScreen` or `roImageCanvas` or is this about one of the dialog screens?

Comment: Hi Nas,I want to set a background using roImageCanvas and provide button press for the images i give there

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set custom background images for any of the built-in screens, only a background color.  You can fake it for [roListScreen](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=3114132) by setting the HDBackgroundImageUrl/SDBackgroundImageUrl [content metadata](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Content+Meta-Data) for every item, but that can make the screen incredibly sluggish to navigate.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [setLayer(0, ...)](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/ifImageCanvas#ifImageCanvas-SetLayerzOrderasIntegercontentMetaDataasObjectasVoid) for the background.

I.e. put the background image in the farthest layer (doesn't have to be z-order 0 but i picked this as example since it's the last visible layer).

Comment: works thanks!!..And how do i pick either a hd image or sd image basing on the TV screen sizes.how to check device size and set the image or text on canvas screen

Comment: [roDeviceInfo.getDisplaySize()](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/ifDeviceInfo#ifDeviceInfo-GetDisplaySizeasObject) and the three previous methods, i think

Comment: ohk,how to pick HD/SD image for background and set.Is it using setLayer again??